# Animate grid background color using storyboard in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, storyboard

I'm new to WPF storyboard. I want to animate grid background color. I'm getting this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve all property
> references in the property path 'Background.Color'. Verify that
> applicable objects support the properties.'

My XAML code:

```
<Grid x:Name="alert_grid">
<Grid.Resources>
<Storyboard x:Key="flashing_storyboard" Storyboard.TargetName="alert_grid">
<ColorAnimation 
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
 From="Black" To="Orange" Duration="0:0:2"
 AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
</Storyboard>
</Grid.Resources>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
Storyboard sb = alert_grid.FindResource("flashing_storyboard") as Storyboard;
if (sb != null)
{
    sb.Begin();
}
```

Any idea how to get the background color animated?

Comment: Background is a brush rather than color. Seeing as you have code there anyhow, you could get the solidcolorbrush out the control's background prooerty and do a color animation in code. Without any storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

```
<Grid Name="alert_grid" Height="75" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,12,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Background="LightGray">
             <Grid.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseLeave">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Name ="flashing_storyboard" Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=alert_grid}">
                        <ColorAnimation To="Orange" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" From="Black" 
         AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" FillBehavior="Stop" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
           </Grid.Triggers>
    </Grid>
```

and code behind

```
Storyboard sb = alert_grid.FindName("flashing_storyboard") as Storyboard;
if (sb != null)
{
   sb.Begin();
}
```